# AngularJS $location.search do not reload page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As my title says, $location.search do not reload page, it just updates the URL. My code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [], function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
    app.controller('mytableCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http) {
        $scope.target = $location.search()["categoryid"];
        $http.get("api/topCategories")
        .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});                        
    });
```

Any suggestions? Are there any alternative for this code?

**Edit:** 
$location.search search for parameter in category.html?categoryid=any_number . It takes any_number number and has to compare it with another value. However, I try to press any a href it just updates the URL, but not reloads page.

Comment: Not understandable. Please elaborate more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added target="_self" in a href tags and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload the page you have to use:

```
var categoryid = 1;
$window.location.href = '/index.html/#' + $location.path() + '?categoryid=' + categoryid;
```

**Note:** Do not forget to include `$window` to your controller

But, if you want to change your path, without reload the hold page, simply

```
var categoryid = 1;
$location.path('/some/new/path' + '?categoryid=' + categoryid);
```

This action will evaluate the ngRoute, and keeps app information as it is.